# subset a dataframe by a list on column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a similar dataframe, lets say `df`

```
x1    x2    x3    
Tom   Grad  35K  
Ada   Secon 21K
John  Grad  47K
Vic   PhD   52K
```

That I need to subset for a list of terms, as for example: `listOfTerms <- c("John", "Nash", "Vic", Mary")`, which should be checked against `df$x1`, resulting in an output which shows me the relevant rows.
I am having hard time to figure out how can it be done, could you please help me?

Comment: `df[df$x1 %in% listOfTerms,]` or `subset(df, x1 %in% listOfTerms)`?

Comment: This works with the given example, but unfortunately not on my actual data :( actually this is the way I was using, and it works. I don't understand why it does not work on my data :(
Thanks

Comment: There was an error in my dataset :| thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata <- data.frame(x1 = c("Tom", "Ada", "John", "Vic"), 
                     x2 = c("Grad", "Secon", "Grad", "PhD"),
                     x3 = c("35k", "21k", "47k", "52k"))

listOfTerms <- c("John", "Nash", "Vic")

subset <- mydata %>%
  filter(x1 %in% listOfTerms)
```